# Add pre-defined value to DataFrame on each instance of matching index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add the corresponding value from df to df1 for each time the name and week match in df1

```py
df
                 Name    Week     Value
0                Frank  Week 3       8.0
1                  Bob  Week 3       8.0
2                  Bob  Week 4       8.0
3            Elizabeth  Week 3       4.0
4                Mario  Week 2       1.5
5                Mario  Week 3       2.5
6             Michelle  Week 3       8.0
7             Michelle  Week 4       1.0
8               Darwin  Week 1       1.0
9               Darwin  Week 2       0.5
10              Darwin  Week 3      11.0
11             Collins  Week 1       8.0
12             Collins  Week 2       6.0
13             Collins  Week 3      17.0
14             Collins  Week 4       7.0
15              Alexis  Week 1       1.5
16              Daniel  Week 3       2.0

df1
                Name    Week  Total
0              Frank  Week 1     16
1              Frank  Week 1      3
2              Frank  Week 3     28
3              Frank  Week 3      1
4              Frank  Week 4      3
..               ...     ...    ...
310           Daniel  Week 2     50
311           Daniel  Week 3     56
312           Daniel  Week 4     78
313            Kevin  Week 4    162
314            Kevin  Week 4     46
```

Expected:

```py
df1
                Name    Week  Total
0              Frank  Week 1     16
1              Frank  Week 1      3
2              Frank  Week 3     **36**
3              Frank  Week 3      **9**
4              Frank  Week 4      3
..               ...     ...    ...
310           Daniel  Week 2     50
311           Daniel  Week 3     **58**
312           Daniel  Week 4     78
313            Kevin  Week 4    162
314            Kevin  Week 4     46
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].
Then please consider formatting your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) + [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
out = (df1
  .merge(df, how='left')
  .assign(Total=lambda d: d['Total'].add(d.pop('Value'), fill_value=0))
)
```

Output:

```
     Name    Week  Total
0   Frank  Week 1   16.0
1   Frank  Week 1    3.0
2   Frank  Week 3   36.0
3   Frank  Week 3    9.0
4   Frank  Week 4    3.0
...
5  Daniel  Week 2   50.0
6  Daniel  Week 3   58.0
7  Daniel  Week 4   78.0
8   Kevin  Week 4  162.0
9   Kevin  Week 4   46.0
```